# How to get Top5 user of a Foursquare Venue

Tags: foursquare

using the Foursquare API I am currently able to get a venue Mayor but can I got the Top5 user?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To get the top 5 (or 10) users for a venue, you'll need to use foursquare's Merchant API and act on the behalf of the venue's manager.

In particular, you'd use the /venues/stats endpoint (https://developer.foursquare.com/merchant/venues/stats.html). For more information about the Merchant API and venue managers, see: https://developer.foursquare.com/merchant/

Answer (score 0):

In short no. The best you can get is the stats from a venue: [Foursquare API Venue](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue.html) those contain: "Contains checkinsCount (total checkins ever here),  usersCount (total users who have ever checked in here), and  tipCount (number of tips here)."

From my experience the API is almost designed to avoid this sort of info gathering. Best way would be watch as people check in to the venue and create your own stats from that information.

Comment: Correct from a standard API point, but I've upvoted Akshay's answer since it does provide a solution for someone who is a venue manager.